# Save AI file without convert it to outline

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

How can I save a AI file/convert it to PDF with text (not to convert it to outline) because I need that PDF in searchable mode?

Answer (score 3):

Go to 'File → Save As' and choose PDF from the 'Save as type' dropdown. This will *not* convert text content to outlines.